# Get total number of ranges of a given length in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array `total` of 12 elements, each element represents and int.  For instance `total[0] = 1`.   I have another array `remaining` that is `total` - `occupied spaces`.  `remaining` will have fewer elements that `total`.

I want to write a method that can look in `total` for instances where there are >= `size` gaps between consecutive ints in the array.  For example:

```
If `foo.total = [1,2,6,7,8,9,]`
then when I call `foo.number_of_slots_available(3)`
I get `2` (because 3,4,5 is not included and 10,11,12 is not included)
```

Here are the beginnings of my method:

```
def number_of_slots(size)
  total_array = (1..12).to_a
  occupied_spaces = some_map.to_a
  remaining_array = total_array - occupied_spaces
  return ????
end
```

Comment: need more in formations.. input numbers and what is your expected output ?

Comment: is 'total' always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable#chunk`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) is the good way to go. Look below.

```
arr = [1,2,6,7,8,9]
rng = (1..12).to_a

rng.chunk { |i| arr.include? i }.to_a
# => [[true, [1, 2]],
#     [false, [3, 4, 5]],
#     [true, [6, 7, 8, 9]],
#     [false, [10, 11, 12]]]

rng.chunk { |i| arr.include? i }.count{|j| j[0] == false} 
# => 2
```

**Edit**

> *"I want to write a method that can look in total for instances where there are >= size gaps between consecutive ints in the array"*

```
arr = [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11]
rng = (1..15).to_a

rng.chunk { |i| arr.include? i }.to_a
# => [[true, [1, 2, 3]],
#     [false, [4, 5]],
#     [true, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
#     [false, [12, 13, 14, 15]]]

rng.chunk { |i| arr.include? i }.count{|j| j[0] == false and j[1].size >= 3 } 
# => 1
rng.chunk { |i| arr.include? i }.count{|j| j[0] == false and j[1].size >= 2 } 
# => 2 
# J[1] is the array,whose size is the actual gap size.
```

Comment: this works generally.  How do I write somehting like `j[0] == false and j[0].size >= n`?

Comment: @JoeEssey I concentrated on your input and expected output - *If `foo.total = [1,2,6,7,8,9,]`
then when I call `foo.number_of_slots_available(3)`
I get `2` (because 3,4,5 is not included and 10,11,12 is not included)*

Comment: I got it.  use `j.size` and ensure the size you're checking against is 1 less than what you want since ruby uses index size here.

Comment: @JoeEssey Did you understand how `#chunk` work? I probably not understood what you mean to say by `j.size`.

Comment: @Priti *"I want to write a method that can look in total for instances where there are >= size gaps between consecutive ints in the array"*. He is talking about being able to adjust the size of the gaps to count.

Comment: @JoeEssey Humm got your point,see my edit.And it is `j[0] == false and j[1].size >= n` instead of `j[0] == false and j[0].size >= n`. `j[1]` is the array,which will give you the *gap size*.

Comment: @Priti You might want to make the size a variable. But +1

Comment: @squiguy You are right. But I think *OP* will now go with this example,to write down his method. But I added another line to show the varieties. :)) I am happy as today I have seen another good use case of `Enumerable#chunk`.

Answer (score 0):

If `total` is sorted is a simple algorithm and should be something like this (I might have some syntax errors):

```
def containsGaps(total, gap)
   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   while i < total.length -1 do
     if total[i+1] - total[i] >= gap then count++;
   end 
   return count;
end
```

And your return might be:

```
return containsGaps(total_array, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I found of doing it.  I modified the method a bit adding in the array to be passed along with the size.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

arr = [1,2,6,7,8,9]
bar = [1,2,3,6,7,10]

def number_of_slots(arr, size)
  count = 0
  range = (1..12).to_a
  # arr.sort! (if the array is not always sorted)
  range.each_cons(size) do |chunk|
    if (chunk & arr).size == 0
      count += 1
    end
  end
  count
end

puts number_of_slots(arr, 3)
puts number_of_slots(bar, 2)
```

Output:

```
2
3
```